# C# recursively go through items in a List of T where T has a List of T

Tags: c#, methods, recursion

So let's say i have a this class T which contains a List variable. How can I go through all items inside of List and then all items inside of each items of the List and so on until every single items have been treated? I know how to do this using a recursive method but i'm wondering if there is a way without using a recursive method that calls itself. Sorry if the question is confusing, a better example using folders could be as

Folder1 > contains Folder2, Folder3, Folder4

Folder2 > contains Folder5, Folder6

```
Folder5 > contains Folder7
```

Folder3 > contains Folder8, Folder9

```
Folder9 > contains Folder10

  Folder10 > contains Folder11
```

I would like to iterate through all of these folders in order (f1, f2, f5, f7, f6, f3, f8, f9, f10, f11, f4)

Does this make more sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Stack stack;
stack.Push(root folder);
while (stack.Count > 0)
{
    Folder f = stack.Pop();
    foreach (Folder subf in f in reverse order)
        stack.Push(subf);
}
```

Comment: I have not tried it but this makes the most sense. I'm gonna try this right now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
static IEnumerable<T> RecursiveEnumerator<T>( IEnumerable root ) {
     if (root is T) yield return (T)root;
     foreach (var item in root) {
         if (item is IEnumerable) {
             foreach (var result in RecursiveEnumerator<T>( (IEnumerable)item )) {
                 yield return result;
             }
         } else {
              if (item is T) yield return (T)item;
         }
     }
     yield break;
 }

 static IEnumerable<T> NonRecursiveEnumerator<T>( T root ) {
     Stack<T> Stack = new Stack<T>( );
     Stack.Push( root );

     do {
         root = Stack.Pop( );
         if (root is T) yield return (T)root;          
         if (root is IEnumerable)
            foreach (var item in ((IEnumerable<T>) root).Reverse()) 
               Stack.Push(item);
     } while (Stack.Count > 0);
     yield break;
  }
```

T shoud be an interface similar to this:

```
interface IStorageElement {
    string Name {get}
}
```

Comment: Of course, these produce a different order (and using a `Stack` instead of a `Queue` would give another order)

Comment: It's still a different order than the recursive method.  However I see no reason to believe that any order is "better" than the others.

Comment: I suppose that is due to he wants to show a folder structure... I have removed the "else" clause to let return intermediate elements..

Answer (score 1):

If the order you mentioned is important and must be exactly followed, your problem would be a [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) over a simple tree. It a famous algorithm and you can find out how to solve it but the algorithm with a good performance is an iterative algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of the foreach. For example

```
foreach(List node in T)
    foreach(List folders in node)
        //do stuff
```

Comment: This is a pretty bad approach because I would need a foreach loop for as deep as it could get.

Comment: I believe recursion would be your only option then.